# Changing background of tabhost workds in ICS but is causing problems in lower versions

Tags: android, transparent, android-tabhost, tabwidget, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

To make the tabhost transparent i have implemented the following code..

```
    for(int i = 0; i < th.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++)
    {
    th.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
```

This changes the background of all the tabs to transparent successfully in ICS but when I test it on 2.2 and 2.3
the first 3 tabs backgrounds are transparent and the last 3 are not(I have 6 tabs in all)(incidentally the 1st 3 tabs are the ones that appear when that activity gets started)

What is causing this and how can i resolve it... Please help..

After applying your suggestion this is what i  included in the code,

```
        th.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            manageTabBackgrounds();
        }

        private void manageTabBackgrounds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i = 0; i < th.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++)
            {
            th.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        }           
    });
```

However this seems to have had no effect on the tabs... Please guide..

Comment: I did check it.. On different devices.
1 running 2.3.5 and 1 running 4.0.3
and then i tested it on emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me..

```
  th.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             for(int i=0;i<th.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
                {
                   th.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); //unselected
                }
                th.getTabWidget().getChildAt(th.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // selected
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do it onTabChanged...

Stick what you have in a function (e.g., "manageTabBackgrounds", then:

```
yourTabHostInstance.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        manageTabBackgrounds();
    }           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent">
    </TabWidget>
```

Comment: Yes.. but it wasn't giving me the result i was looking for.. Thanks for your efforts anyways..:)
I answered the question with the code that was giving me the output I wanted..